How to pass authentication token to websocket call in QlikSense
I am creating a simple mashup and it generates below config --
var config = {
host: window.location.hostname,
prefix: prefix,
port: window.location.port,
isSecure: window.location.protocol === "https:"
};

This is then used to make websocket calls , like
https://<host>:<port>/<prefix>/app/engineData?reloadUri=....

I am exposing the dashboard through a different domain. I need to authenticate separately and pass a 'token' to this websocket call.
Like
https://<host>:<port>/<prefix>/app/engineData?reloadUri=....&token=<TOKEN>

How to configure the config options to pass this token in every websocket call?
This question is for Qlik Sense enterprise edition.

You are almost there. Just add it to the webcoscket as a url parameter &qlikTicket=<TICKET>
If you want more details, then ive wrote a blog post that describes the whole workflow. You can read it here.

While creating mashup/extension from dev-hub , how to change the config to pass &token= to websocket url ?

Are you trying to connect to the same Qlik instance on which you are developing? If thats the case then technically you dont need to pass any tokens. Since you are connecting from the same origin then the browser will automatically send the session cookie when connection is open/establishing.

I am trying to connect QS instance from a different server
